# Select every k-th element from Eigen matrix or vector?

Tags: matrix, eigen

In Eigen, I have an `M x kN` real matrix, stored in the default column-major order. Each of the `M` rows contains `N k`-tuples; e g, for `k=3, (a0 b0 c0 a1 b1 c1 ... aN bN cN)`.

How can I extract vectors (or a matrix whose rows or columns are a set of kN vectors) containing every `k-`th element; e g, `(a0 a1 ... aN), (b0 b1 ... bN)`, etc.

64-bit Windows 7, Visual C++

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Eigen::Map` and set the outer stride to `k * m.cols()`.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int sz = 8;
    Eigen::MatrixXd m(8,8);

    Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(m.data(), sz*sz).setLinSpaced(1., sz*sz);

    std::cout << m << "\n\n";
    int k = 2;
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd, 0, Eigen::Stride<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> 
        mp(m.data(), sz, sz/k, Eigen::Stride<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>( k*m.cols(),1));

    std::cout << mp << "\n\n";

    Eigen::MatrixXd m2 = mp;

    std::cout << m2 << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `k*m.rows()` in the stride for `mp`. With that change, I get the correct first element of each tuple. What is the easiest way to get the second,...`,`k-th elements?

Comment: Easiest method to get the `p`th element would be to pass `m.data() + p` to the `Map`.

Comment: Works just as advertised. Now I just need a visualizer for the map (Visual Studio .natvis file).

Comment: The "`p`-th element" that I wanted is accessed by `m.data+p*m.rows()`, because `m` is stored in column-major order, not row-major.